# Discordjs v14: Multiple post reaction on same channel button handle problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I created a code to get a rank with the reaction, but in this code, when a 2nd post is sent, it ignores the buttons in the 2nd post as if it does not exist and instead perceives it as clicking the buttons in the first post.

Before this, I was giving the id of the buttons through the index, I updated it to nanoid, but I still have the same problem. The bot takes into account the first post anyway.

```js
function buttonBuilder(buttonName, role) {
  return new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId(buttonName)
    .setLabel(role.name)
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary);
}

const roles = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((i) => {
  const id = nanoid(7).toLocaleLowerCase();
  return {
    name: `role${id}`,
    buttonName: `button${id}`,
  };
});

function getData() {
  const command = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("react-role")
    .setDescription("Reaction Role Messege")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("title")
        .setDescription("Title.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("description")
        .setDescription("Description.")
        .setRequired(true)
    );

  for (const [index, role] of roles.entries()) {
    command.addRoleOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName(role.name)
        .setDescription(`Role ${role.name} (Optional)`)
        .setRequired(index < 2)
    );
  }

  return command;
}

export default {
  data: getData(),

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const title = interaction.options.getString("title");
    const description = interaction.options.getString("description");

    const button = new ActionRowBuilder();

    for (const role of roles) {
      const roleOption = interaction.options.getRole(role.name);
      if (roleOption) {
        button.addComponents(buttonBuilder(role.buttonName, roleOption));
      }
    }

    const styledDescription = description.split("|").join("\n");

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("#4e4072")
      .setTitle(title)
      .setDescription(styledDescription);

    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      components: [button],
      fetchReply: true,
    });

    const collector =
      await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();

    collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
      const member = i.member;

      const role = roles.find((r) => {
        return r.buttonName === i.customId;
      });

      if (role) {
        const roleStat = interaction.options.getRole(role.name);
        await roleChecker(member, roleStat, i);
        await interaction.editReply({
          embeds: [embed],
          components: [button],
          fetchReply: true,
        });
      }
    });
  },
};

async function roleChecker(member, roleStat, i) {
  if (member.roles.cache.has(roleStat.id)) {
    await i
      .reply({
        embeds: [
          {
            title: `${roleStat.name} role is deleted!`,
            description: `${member.user.username}, ${roleStat.name} role is deleted!`,
          },
        ],
        ephemeral: true,
      })
      .then(() => setTimeout(() => i.deleteReply(), 5000));
    return member.roles.remove(roleStat);
  } else {
    await i
      .reply({
        embeds: [
          {
            title: `You have got ${roleStat.name} role!`,
            description: `${member.user.username}, you have got ${roleStat.name} role!`,
          },
        ],
        ephemeral: true,
        fetchReply: true,
      })
      .then(() => setTimeout(() => i.deleteReply(), 5000));
    return member.roles.add(roleStat);
  }
}
```

Image of when I click test-6 rank it gives test-1:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you have 5 `roles`. What do you expect the 6th button to return?

Comment: Actually i was trying to do with 10 roles but button reponse seems limited to 5. Then i tried to change 5 per post but it didnt work

Answer (score -1):

Has it worked before you applied the change of splitting the buttons over separate messages?
As your code currently only supports a single interaction reply instead of the result gotten in the image, it must be related to the code you changed in between that period.
(Is the code you posted, your most up-to-date code snippet?)

**How I see your code currently, it should work.**
What I could potentially think goes wrong with spreading the buttons over two followup replies, is that you may not properly register the component collectors on them.
As a component collector does not read components made after the component collector was registered to the channel, you have to create a new component collector and assign it to that followup, or re-register the component collector.
E.g.

```js
const collector = await interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();

const followup = await interaction.followUp(...);
followUp.createMessageComponentCollect();
// ...
```

Alternatively, you could use the interactionCreate method and check for buttons that way

```js
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    // ...
});
```

[Related guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#receiving-button-interactions)

What could be a potential issue in the future is that the cache you're relying on might not always update, as the cache may not always be updated after assigning a role, so you may need to fetch it manually after doing so.

Comment: `CommandInteraction` does have an [`options` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=options), and that does have a [`getRole` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getRole). The documentation is pretty clear on this.

Comment: This is true, my bad. I failed to see the difference between the Interaction and CommandInteraction class.